# Confusion about NoSQL Design

Tags: mongodb, visualization, nosql

I know that the NoSQL is not the relational database therefore I cannot draw the ERD or other method which can only be applied to relational database.

My confusion is: What kind of method or diagram should I illustrate to design a NoSQL database?

Thanks.

Comment: Good question. Consider adding 'visualization' as a tag, and maybe correcting the two typos ('noly', 'illstrate')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an abstract from a recent 10gen event presentation suggesting that mind maps are the most logical tool for the job. I expect more specialized tools to emerge, but in general, mind maps align well with non-relational schema design.

"Most of us are visual learners. Often, visual learners will find that information "clicks" when it is explained with the aid of a chart or picture. For MongoDB that picture is a leaf representing a natural approach to databases. In the RDBMS world a database schema is "visualized" through an Entity Relationship (ER) diagram. An ER diagram is the primary communication tool about an RDBMS data model. MongoDB provides a powerful dynamic database schema. However it is sometimes difficult to visualize. An accurate visualization of a MongoDB schema dramatically increases the ability to communicate the flexibility and power MongoDB between developers, architects, DBAs and end users. A mind map is a visual thinking tool that helps structure information, do better analysis, comprehend, synthesize and generate new ideas. Its power lies in its simplicity, much like MongoDB. Using a mind mapping open source tool, a clear and vibrant visualization of a dynamic MongoDB schema can be created that "clicks." Further, it works the other way around - mind maps can be used to create a dynamic schema in MongoDB. The mind mapping process allows non-technical business users to visually develop their requirements on the fly. During design process the mind map provides a flexible visual tool which changes in a fluid manner."

Answer (score 0):

You can fairly easily use the standard tools however it depends upon your specific scenario and the problem you are looking to solve. I recently had a conversation about this actually: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/xZCwEm06eU4 which might help however that conversation is also quite specialised.

I have been thinking ever since that instead of repeating myself on this I should actually write a manual for drawing UML diagrams, MongoDB style.

Maybe if you explain your perspective on what UML diagram you wish to draw then we could provide a more detailed answer on how to accomplish a type of NoSQL representation of them.

Comment: Would be interested to see such manual (I do realize this thread is 2 years old by now). My extra "need" is to document the changing nature of a MongoDB document, i.e. not only the way it is now, but how it's evolved. Since we might leave the old data as-is, and need to access it, unlike in an SQL database where one would revise the structure as well.