# How i can embedde colletion in mongoDB

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

if i write query like this

```
SELECT student.name, class.subj
            FROM student
            INNER JOIN class
            ON student.class_id = class.class_id;
```

in MySql so how i can write for mongoDB script ?

Comment: Typo ..should be `INNER JOIN` instead of `INNER JION`

Comment: `student`  and `class` is my `table or collection` name

Comment: thanks @ Shankar Damodaran for correct my key word

Comment: The MongoDb docs, and many stackoverflow posts make it clear that joins of any type aren't directly supported by MongoDb. If you need Joins, you either aren't using the right database or need to better understand how to model data in MongoDb. I'd start here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB **does not support** joins because join operations make database response slower. You should change your thinking style while designing a database. If you use your documents together, it is suggested to make them embedded documents. Here is a tip for designing based on relations :

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models-relationships/

Some of data modeling documents are below :

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/
http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/nosql/w/wiki/349.mongodb-data-modeling.aspx#Collection
http://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/

Comment: Thanks @myildirim i got your meaning by this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010408/equivalent-of-erd-for-mongodb)  :) i think i can use `select` in `select` to solve this problem. but i still think may be have someone have any solution good than me.so plz give me a simple example if u can to get result like it