# Is it possible to make ER (entity-relation) diagram of Non SQL Databases like firebase?

Tags: firebase, entity-relationship, erd

I am working on my university project and I am using Firebase as a database for which I have to make UML diagram. I had mostly seen the example for ER(entity-relation) Diagram in SQL databases. I also heard that ER Diagram is created only for SQL databases. We can create relation in Firebase but can we create ER Diagram for The non-SQL databases like entity relation diagram for firebase.

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6010408/13130697)?

Comment: ER is not UML...

Comment: So ERD is not necessary need for non SQL database